# Use CSS Animations to keep elements upright while rotating in a circle

Tags: css, css-animations

I have about 10 icons, all arranged in the shape of a circle with a diameter of about 400 pixels. The icons are each 80x80.

I'd like to have these icons rotate around in a circle, but when I implement the animation, the icons themselves currently rotate as well-- so for instance, the one on the bottom becomes upside-down.

Is there any way to have them rotate together in a circle but keep the icons themselves upright?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Courtesy of http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/

This fiddle solves it: http://jsfiddle.net/cswkd/

Good question!